# How do you match by date in mongodb using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a dataset in a mongo database with elements like this:

```
{
    "fullname" : "Anonymous User",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-09T04:00:27Z")
}
```

I am trying to search on the date *and* fullname terms.

In mongo (on the command line) if I do the following command I get a number of elements returned:

```
db.collection_name.find({ $and: [ { fullname: { $regex: "^Anonymous User$", $options: 'i' } }, {"date" : {"$lt" : ISODate("2016-12-19T00:00:00Z")}} ] }).pretty()
```

when the fullname matches and the date is less than the date given.  This is great so I know my database has the data stored but the date and name are hard-coded.

I am writing a script in node.js and came up with this:

```
    var fullname = "Anonymous User";
    var today = new Date();
    var search_term = { $and: [ { fullname: { $regex: "^" + fullname + "$", $options: 'i' } }, { date: { $lt: today } } ] };
```

I am trying to use the [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) module and this snippet of code in my nodejs script:

> db.collection( collection_name ).find( search_term ).toArray( function
> ( err, results ) { console.log(results); } );

But when I run my script no results are returned.  There are no error messages - just that no items match and there are no results.

What am I doing wrong?

I think it may be something to do with how the date gets stored in the variable "search_term" but I don't know how to fix this.  For example this works:

```
db.collection( collection_name ).find( { $and: [ { fullname: { $regex: "^Anonymous User$", $options: 'i' } }, { date: { $lt: new Date() } } ] } );
```

This doesn't work:

> db.collection( collection_name ).find( search_term ).toArray( function
> ( err, results ) { console.log(results); } );

The only difference being I have replaced the find statement with "search_term".

I want to use the latter to avoid code duplication.

Comment: date format should be in this form in $gte or $lte
2016-12-19T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: $gte or $lte ?  Can I not just use $gt or $le?

Comment: no, you can use any from $lte, $gte, $lt and $lte

Comment: try wrapping the search term in the brackets [{ $and: [ { fullname: { $regex: "^" + fullname + "$", $options: 'i' } }, { date: { $lt: today } } ] }]

Comment: Wrapping the search term in square brackets did not help either I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it like this

```
var today = new Date().toISOString()
```

Comment: I tried doing that (as well as getTime()) but it still returns no results.

Comment: did you try it without the regex on the fullname?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with just the date search like this: { date: { $lt: today }

Still no results are returned.